# Control the position of the slider thumb

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this comparison Slider and on page refresh I want the position of the Dot(thumb) of the range slider to be in the middle and not take the same position as before the page refresh.
[position image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBEhm.jpg)

So when reloading the page the range slider is not even to the current "Compare" position

```js
let slideValue = document.querySelectorAll('.jsSliderComparison')
slideValue.forEach((clicker) => {
  clicker.addEventListener('input', sliderComparison)
})

function sliderComparison(e) {
  slideValue.forEach((el) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.jsSliderComparer').forEach((element) => {
      element.style.clipPath =
        'polygon(0 0,' +
        e.target.value +
        '% 0,' +
        e.target.value +
        '% 100%, 0 100%)'
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="slider slider--comparison">
  <img src="SOURCE" />
  <img class="jsSliderComparer" src="SOURCE" />
  <input max="100" min="0" value="50" type="range" class="jsSliderComparison" />
</div>
```

Solution:
Set a default on load

```
slideValue.forEach((loader) => {
  loader.value = 50
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The Range Slider should have the same position as the line showing the comparison when reloaded

Comment: What if you execute `sliderComparison` on page load with the element as argument?